# Breaking a wide dataframe to two uneven column dataframe and change it to long formate

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr

I have a wide table with more than 22 columns. This table is the result of `fuzzymatch` and that's why it's in wide format. The column names are shown below (in order) (I will try to create a sample data frame for better demonstration):

```
 [1] "shift_date.x"  "shift"   "ageyrs"   "site"   "level"            
 [6] "crowded_shift"    "time"    "dd"     "AE"    "ageyrs_start"    
[11] "ageyrs_end"    "time_start"     "time_end"     "shift_date.y"     "shift_n"   
[16] "ageyrs_n"     "site_n"   "level_n"   "crowded_shift_n"  "los_n"           
[21] "dd_n" "AE_n"
```

What I want to do is to break this data frame starting from column 14 to the end ("shift_date.y" to "AE_n") and add it as new rows to the bottom of first section of table (change it to long format). **The problem is** that the first section has 13 columns but the second part has 8 and I am not sure how I can combine them (that's why probably `subsetting` and `rbind` don't work).

As an example, imagine we have the following data frame:

```
shift <- c (2,1,0)
ageyrs <- c(12.2,13,14)
site <- c(0,1,3)
level <- c (1,5,6)
ageyrs_s <- c (2,4,5)
ageyrs_n <- c (4,6,8)
shift2 <- c (2,1,0)
ageyrs2 <- c(12.2,13,14)
site2 <- c(0,1,3)
level2 <- c (1,5,6)

a <- data.frame(shift, ageyrs, site, level, ageyrs_s, ageyrs2, shift2, ageyrs2, site2, level2)


  shift ageyrs site level ageyrs_s ageyrs_n shift_n ageyrs_n site_n level_n
1     2   12.2    0     1        2        4      2    12.2     0      1
2     1   13.0    1     5        4        6      1    13.0     1      5
3     0   14.0    3     6        5        8      0    14.0     3      6
```

No I want to break this dataframe at "shift2" column and create a dataframe line shown below:

```
 shift ageyrs site level ageyrs_s ageyrs_n
1     2   12.2    0     1        2        4
2     1   13.0    1     5        4        6
3     0   14.0    3     6        5        8
4     2   12.2    0     1       NA       NA
5     1   13.0    1     5       NA       NA
6     0   14.0    3     6       NA       NA
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split.default` from `base R` to split the data into `list` of data.frames and then convert to a single `data.frame` after `unlist`ing the `list` elements

```
nm1 <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(a))
lst1 <-  lapply(split.default(a, nm1),
      unlist, use.names = FALSE)
out <- data.frame(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))[unique(nm1)]
```

-output

```
out
#  shift ageyrs site level ageyrs_s ageyrs_n
#1     2   12.2    0     1        2        4
#2     1   13.0    1     5        4        6
#3     0   14.0    3     6        5        8
#4     2   12.2    0     1       NA       NA
#5     1   13.0    1     5       NA       NA
#6     0   14.0    3     6       NA       NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

a %>% 
  rename_at(vars(shift:level), ~ str_c(., '1')) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ageyrs_s, ageyrs_n), names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
     names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])")
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what "a" is? is it my main data frame?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you yes, it is the one you created in the post

Comment: Thanks, the output I got is different from what you showed above. It has "ageyrs1, ageyrs2,... as the index number and it's not in order of the main dataset. Is there any way to fix these? I guess probably reindexing and ...?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you i updated the option.  You just need to change the column order as in the original dataset

Comment: Great, now I guess it's working. Just a quick question, I guess by using nm1 <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(a)) , you are changing column name "shift2" to "shift", is it correct? what if I want to change "shift_n" to "shift"? I can't use "\\d+$", is it correct?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you It is basedon a pattern that `\\d+$` implies one or more digits at the end.  If you want to also check for `_n`, then the pattern would be `(\\d+|_n)$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use `bind_rows()` and `setNames()` to define common names so that the values can be joined properly:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newa <- a %>% select(shift:ageyrs_n) %>%
  bind_rows(a %>% select(shift2:level2) %>% setNames(gsub('2','',names(.))))
```

Output:

```
  shift ageyrs site level ageyrs_s ageyrs_n
1     2   12.2    0     1        2        4
2     1   13.0    1     5        4        6
3     0   14.0    3     6        5        8
4     2   12.2    0     1       NA       NA
5     1   13.0    1     5       NA       NA
6     0   14.0    3     6       NA       NA
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it didn't work. following your approach, I wrote this code


result_match_2_long <- result_match_2_modified %>% select(shift_date.x:los_end) %>%
  bind_rows(result_match_2_modified %>% select(shift_date.y:AEoutcome_n) %>% setNames(gsub('_n','',names(.))))

Comment: I replied in the answer section. Unfortunately, this approach didn't work. Is it because "shift_date.y" doesn't have "_n"?  you can see the name of actual columns I have in the body of the question